# How to change Kubernetes garbage collection threshold values

Tags: garbage-collection, kubernetes, azure-container-service

By default, image-gc-high-threshold and image-gc-low-threshold values are 90 and 80% respectively.

We want to change them to 80 and 70, How we can change the Kubernetes image garbage collection threshold values.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the garbage collection thresholds can be done using switches on the `kubelet`.

From [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)

```
--image-gc-high-threshold int32    The percent of disk usage after which image garbage collection is always run. (default 85)
--image-gc-low-threshold int32     The percent of disk usage before which image garbage collection is never run. Lowest disk usage to garbage collect to. (default 80)
```

Comment: In k3s these switches go into `/etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml` under `kubelet-arg: - "image-gc-high-threshold=74"`